# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
 $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://myurl',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
     data:  JSON.stringify(data)  
  }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.message;
```

this is working only when I enable CORS Filter plugin in chrome.Searched a lot for solution. None of them are working properly. please help.

Comment: It appears that you are consuming an API which is different from your Domain and it does not have __'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'__ header..

Comment: what do you mean by that? is there any particular way to solve this problem?

Comment: Either you should consume APIs under samedomain or your server should have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow you to access it...

Comment: i cannot add any headers to the sever which is already up. what can i do from my side?

Comment: `what can i do from my side?` nothing - CORS protects resources

Comment: if i deploy my program in the same system on which the server runs will solve the problem?

Comment: Generally, yes. Whatever page this javascript is on, it should be served from the `myurl` domain if you wish to avoid this issue entirely. Otherwise, you need to set up the server to allow cross-domain access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved....! I hosted the client on the same domain on which the web service is running. Now client and server are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code in the REST service to allow CORS request. This link will be useful : https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

Comment: can you tell me more specifically about what i have to do?